# Mobile app navigation not in sync with web

Tags: sharepoint-online, mobile

I have sharepoint intranet, using a nav bar in the top to navigate between sites.
However in my mobile app this navigation isn't getting displayed properly.

In my mobile app if i unfold the side menu, i see several buttons but these are the buttons from the navigation on the left side of the page, not the top. (+ some buttons that aren't on my webpage to begin with).

Any clue as to what could be wrong and why the navigation isn't taken over properly ?